# Suffix subdirectory name with number of files underneath it

Tags: directory, suffix

I have subdirectories a b c.     For various obscure reasons,  I would like to count all files recursively underneath these and only for maxdepth=1 mindepth=1  suffix this first layer of subdirectories with the file count down to the bottom of each subdirectory tree (no limit).

So if a and its subdirectories have 23 files,  b...64 and c...82   I will end up with subdirectories renamed as

a_23
b_64
c_82

I have a routine to count recursively:

```
function count_all_files () {
echo "enter directory"
find "$1" -type f | wc -l
}
```

but am at a loss how to construct a find -exec operation to rename as I need.

Something like this pseudo code.

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 "*" -exec $(count_all_files {}) && [suffix dir name]
```

Grateful for thoughts.  Needs to work with directories containing spaces too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working.   I have amended it so it always makes a clean update eg if you add new files.

```
function label_subdirectories_number_files () {

for file in *_my_dir_count_* ; do rename 's/_my_dir_count_.*//g' "$file" ; done 
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -exec bash -c 'cd {}  \
&& number_of_files=$(find . -type f | wc -l)  && directory=$(pwd) \
&& directory="${directory## }"  && read -r number_of_files <<< "$number_of_files" \
&& new_directory="$directory""_my_dir_count_""$number_of_files"  && \mv "$directory" "$new_directory" '  &> /dev/null 2>&1 \;
}
```

This variation does selected number of lower subdirectories too in case you want a quick eyeball test of lower level counts.

```
function label_subdirectories_number_files_many () {
echo "enter number of levels to scan"
for file in *_my_dir_count_* ; do rename 's/_my_dir_count_.*//g' "$file" &> /dev/null 2>&1 ; done

for zcount in $(seq 1 "$1") ; do
echo "level =  $zcount out of  $1 "
find . -type d -mindepth $zcount -maxdepth $zcount -name '*' -exec bash -c 'cd {}  \
&& number_of_files=$(find . -type f | wc -l)  && directory=$(pwd) \
&& directory="${directory## }"  && read -r number_of_files <<< "$number_of_files" \
&& new_directory="$directory""_my_dir_count_""$number_of_files"  && \mv "$directory" "$new_directory" '  &> /dev/null 2>&1 \;

done
}
```